# Snakemake WorkflowError: Failed to group jobs together

Tags: slurm, snakemake

**BACKGROUND:** I have to adapt my Snakemake pipeline from a single-node usage to a cluster with resource management. With a SLURM-specific Snakemake profile, my rules are successfully submitted as SLURM jobs, so I continued to add the Snakemake directive `resources` to every non-local rule to optimize queue scheduling. These settings were adopted and my pipeline finished as intended.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
rule ruleA:
    group: "group_1_init"
    resources:
        cpus=1,
        time="00:04:00"

rule ruleB:
    group: "group_1_init"
    resources:
        cpus=1,
        time="00:05:00"
```

`ruleA` and `ruleB` are submitted as a single job to a computing node.

**PROBLEM:** My pipeline has many small, single-CPU jobs that I binned with the Snakemake rule directive `group`. Here is the error:

```
WorkflowError:
Failed to group jobs together. Resource time is a string but not all group jobs require the same value. Observed: 00:05:00 != 00:04:00.
```

I guess, there should be only one `resource` setting per group but I could not find online resources on the logic behind it.

**QUESTION:** How do I define my varying resource requirements in group jobs? Should e.g. `time` reflect the computing time of the whole group of jobs or does Snakemake sum-up rule times within a group as a parameter for the SLURM job submission. For `cpus` in turn, that would be the max cpus among all rules.

Comment: Have you tried defining the time resource using an integer number of seconds?  I think SLURM can take the time requirement in that form. This way snakemake might be able to combine them.

Comment: Is there a reason you're defining a "cpus" resource and not using the built in `threads` variable?

Comment: @Marmaduke Thank you. You put me on the right track. I used the SLURM convention in the Snakefile for defining the computing time, the string 'time="00:04:00"', but Snakemake requires this to be an integer in the unit Minutes. With latter, it worked fine. since Slurm can take time in minutes.

Comment: In my Snakefile, I use both. The rule directive "threads" to be used as a variable in the run/shell directive and the variable "resources|cpus" to communicate the demands to the Slurm queue.

Comment: I've been able to use `threads` for both. I'm using the `--cluster` command line option something like this: `snakemake ... --cluster "sbatch -c {threads} ..."`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without parameter conversion by an additional script, the resource `time` has to be an *integer* and is interpreted as *minutes*. This is the correction:

```
rule ruleA:
    group: "group_1_init"
    resources:
        cpus=1,
        time=4
rule ruleB:
    group: "group_1_init"
    resources:
        cpus=1,
        time=5
```